# How do I paginate posts page with $wpdb?

Tags: posts, pagination, navigation, get-posts, nextpage

I am using this to get the posts:

```
(...) if ( empty( $categories_defined) ) {

  $posts = get_posts($args);
} else {
  global $wpdb;
  $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE
    post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND
    post_title LIKE %s  ORDER BY post_title ASC LIMIT 50",
    $categories_defined . '%'
  ) );
}
```

So I have already limited my posts, which is working fine, but I can't get the pagination. I tried using a plugin, shortcodes and the native pagination, but I can't find the problem. Can someone help me out with this? I'd like to have a `next` and `previous` pagination together with the navigation with numbers... One for above, one beneath the posts...

Comment: Where you put this code? In a page or in a singular post or in an archive template? Tip: for the else you can use the `s` argument for get_posts instad writng a custom SQL

Comment: In a page that I am using. Can you provide an example of what you mean with s?

Comment: Please take a look at `like_prepare()` for your query.

Comment: Don't get it. What does it? There is not much documentation out there?

Comment: Why are you not just using get_posts() for this?

Comment: Because it's a custom query that must be done with MySQL.